# Can't verify an address on-chain

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps

I am working on a project related state channel. The functions related to verification is:

```
function verify(
        address _address,
        string memory message,
        uint256 nonce,
        bytes memory _signature
    ) private view {
        bytes32 messageHash = getMessageHash(message,nonce);
        bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash = ethSignedMessageHash(messageHash);
        address signer = ECDSA.recover(_ethSignedMessageHash, _signature);
        console.log(signer);
    }

    function getMessageHash(
        string memory message,
        uint256 nonce
    ) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message, nonce)));
    }

    function ethSignedMessageHash(
        bytes32 _hash
    ) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return (
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash)
            )
        );
    }
```

To check those functions works properly or not i used eth.build by Austin griffith. I signed a message, generated a signature there and called `verify()` with that message and signature in remix ide, I should get the address who signed the message, right?? But i am getting another address. How to get the address who signed the message.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the encoded packed message, instead of the message hash, to `ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash()` function. You can do this by calling `abi.encodePacked()` on the message before passing it to the function. Here's an updated code that should work:

```
function verify(string memory message, bytes memory _signature) public pure returns (address){
    bytes memory messageEncodedPacked = abi.encodePacked(message);

    bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(messageEncodedPacked);
    address signer = ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash, _signature);

    return signer;
}
```

With this code, you should be able to recover the address of the signer who signed the message.

Comment: Not working, same as before

Comment: Please see my new answer @Hacek

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test case with ***Hardhat*** for your code:

verify.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";


contract TestVerify {

  function verify(string memory message, uint256 nonce, bytes memory _signature) public pure returns (address){
    bytes32 messageEncodedPacked = getMessageHash(message, nonce);

    bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash = ethSignedMessageHash(messageEncodedPacked);
    address signer = ECDSA.recover(_ethSignedMessageHash, _signature);

    return signer;
  }


  function getMessageHash(string memory message, uint256 nonce) private pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message, nonce));
  }

  function ethSignedMessageHash(bytes32 _hash) private pure returns (bytes32) {
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash)));
  }

  function getEncodePacked(string memory message, uint256 nonce) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    return abi.encodePacked(message, nonce);
  }
}
```

Test Case:

```
const {loadFixture} = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");

describe("Test Signature Verification", function () {
  async function deploy() {
    const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestVerify");
    const contract = await Contract.deploy();
    return {contract};
  }

  describe("", function () {
    it("Test", async function () {

      let mnemonic = "announce room limb pattern dry unit scale effort smooth jazz weasel alcohol"
      let wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic)

      console.log('our wallet address: ', wallet.address);

      let message = "Hello Hacek";
      let nonce = 10

      let payload = ethers.utils.solidityPack(["string", "uint256"], [message, nonce]);
      let payloadHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(payload);
      let signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(payloadHash));


      // get contract instance
      const {contract} = await loadFixture(deploy);

      // print EncodePacked
      console.log('our code payload: ', payload.toString())
      console.log('contract payload: ', await contract.getEncodePacked(message, nonce))


      let address = await contract.verify(message, nonce, signature);
      console.log('address returned: ', address);

      console.log('address is equal:', address === wallet.address)
    });
  });
});
```

Run `npx hardhat test` and result:

```
  Test Signature Verification
    
our wallet address:  0x71CB05EE1b1F506fF321Da3dac38f25c0c9ce6E1
our code payload:  0x48656c6c6f20486163656b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
contract payload:  0x48656c6c6f20486163656b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
address returned:  0x71CB05EE1b1F506fF321Da3dac38f25c0c9ce6E1
address is equal: true
      ✔ Test (1787ms)


  1 passing (2s)
```